# Unable to avoid copying while pushing objects with copy-construcor into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, move, copy-constructor, emplace

I'm trying to avoid copying with `emplace_back()` and `reserve()`. But when I've tried to do it, i caught myself getting 3 copies for reason i cannot really understand. `reserve()` actually helps to avoid copying, but `emplace_back()` actually does nothing with it (works the same way as `push_back()` in this case). Here's the code:

```cpp
struct Vertex
{
    size_t x, y, z;

    Vertex(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }

    Vertex(const Vertex& v)
        : x(v.x), y(v.y), z(v.z)
    {
        std::cout << "\nCOPIED!\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vert;

    vert.reserve(3);
    vert.emplace_back(Vertex(1, 2, 3));
    vert.emplace_back(Vertex(4, 5, 6));
    vert.emplace_back(Vertex(7, 8, 9));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 3 times 'COPIED!'. Well i tried to something like this:

```
    vert.emplace_back(std::move(Vertex(1, 2, 3)));
    vert.emplace_back(std::move(Vertex(4, 5, 6)));
    vert.emplace_back(std::move(Vertex(7, 8, 9)));
```

to convert my objects into r-values, but again i got 3 times 'COPIED!'.

Then i tried to push the same object 3 times with `std::move` and without and again got the same result:

```
    Vertex vertex(1, 2, 3);
    vert.emplace_back(vertex);
    vert.emplace_back(vertex);
    vert.emplace_back(vertex);
```

or

```
    Vertex vertex(1, 2, 3);
    vert.emplace_back(std::move(vertex));
    vert.emplace_back(std::move(vertex));
    vert.emplace_back(std::move(vertex));
```

I don't understand what am i doing wrong. I use MSVS 2022 Preview C++14. Also i tried to do it on C++14/17/20 and same result. Is there a way to get rid of all of the copies? Or maybe i understand situation wrong?

Comment: Make it `vert.emplace_back(1, 2, 3);`. The whole point of `emplace_back` is that you can pass in parameters to the object's constructor that the vector can use to construct the object in place, rather than an object instance that will then have to be copied. The way you use it, it's no different from `push_back`

Comment: You cannot `std::move` your object as it doesn't have a move-constructor.

Comment: You use `std::move`, but because you have user-declared copy constructor, you have blocked possibility of compiler creating move constructor for your class. You need to declare a move constructor (e.g. with `Vertex(Vertex&&) = default;`).

Comment: Even if there was a move-constructor, there are no managed resources for the class member variables, so there is nothing to move.  So in this case, a move does the same thing as a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::move` isn't useful here. The temporary `Vertex` object is already a prvalue, so casting it to an xvalue doesn't change anything. The class has no move constructor, so copy initialisation cannot move; it has to copy. The implicit move constructor has been inhibited by the user defined copy constructor. Although, the move constructor couldn't be any faster than the copy constructor for this class anyway.

The way that `emplace_back` works is that it forwards the arguments to the constructor of the element. If the argument that you pass is an object of the element type, then you invoke the constructor that accepts another instance of the class - that is the copy constructor (or the move constructor for classes that have it).

Instead of creating a temporary `Vertex` object, and passing it as an argument to `emplace_back`, you should pass the three `size_t` objects that can be forwarded to the constructor `Vertex(size_t, size_t, size_t)`. This way you can avoid copying (and moving) of the `Vertex` object entirely:

```
vert.emplace_back(1, 2, 3);
vert.emplace_back(4, 5, 6);
vert.emplace_back(7, 8, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you provided a custom copy constructor for `struct Vertex`, no move constructor was automatically generated. Attempting to move this struct will use the copy constructor, as you observed.

Add a custom move constructor:

```
Vertex(Vertex &&v)
    : x(std::move(v.x)), y(std::move(v.y)), z(std::move(v.z))
{
    std::cout << "MOVED!\n";
}
```

But note that other than for printing, here you don't need neither custom copy nor move constructor. The implicitly generated ones should be enough.

---

> ```
> std::move(Vertex(1, 2, 3))
> ```

`std::move` doesn't change anything here, because `Vertex(1, 2, 3)` is already an rvalue.

---

> but `emplace_back()` .... works the same way as `push_back()` in this case

Yes. For it to make a difference, you need to pass constructor arguments directly into it, as mentioned in @eerorika's answer:

```
vert.emplace_back(1, 2, 3);
```

This will get rid of the copy/move, by constructing the object directly in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a POD (Plain Old Data) by adding a default constructor :

```
struct Vertex
{
    size_t x, y, z;

    Vertex() = default;

    Vertex(size_t xx, size_t yy, size_t zz) : x{xx}, y{yy}, z{zz} {}
};
```